# Make an Image act like a button in Java swing without features of actual Jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

[image] here I have created an image which looks like a 3d button and I want to use it as a button in java swing for my application.

I tried the following code:

```
 ImageIcon water = new ImageIcon("button.jpeg"); 
    exceptionButton = new JButton(water);
```

I got it as image but it had featured like border of the button so i used the following code:

```
   exceptionButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    exceptionButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    exceptionButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    exceptionButton.setOpaque(false);
```

But it didnt help. I want the actual image to act as a button. The image has rounded corners but right now the image is coming in the button and loosing its actual effect of rounded corners. Also I want it focussed when a user brings mouse over it. Since I have put image for button with above code, I am not getting the effect of button press when user clicks on it.

How should I change my code?

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513)?

Answer (score 1):

> The image has rounded corners but right now the image is coming in the button and loosing its actual effect of rounded corners.

Don't use an EmptyBorder, that will always be Rectangular. Also try using `setBorderPainted(false)`.

> Also I want it focussed when a user brings mouse over it. Since I have put image for button with above code

Then you will also need to provide a rollover icon. See `setRolloverIcon(...)`

Comment: I tried usinf setBorderPainted but its not showing any effect. The image is inside the rectangular box of the button

Answer (score 0):

use jlabel instead of jbutton

```
 jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(youriconpath)); 
jLabel5.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jLabel5MouseClicked(evt);
    }
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jLabel5MouseEntered(evt);
    }
    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jLabel5MouseExited(evt);
    }
});

    private void jLabel5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        // write your code 
    }                                    

    private void jLabel5MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        //change your jlabel icon 
        jLabel5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("yourNewIconpath"));
    }                                    

    private void jLabel5MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        //resete your icon 
    }
```